# Real-time communication without requiring a server in-between

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am trying to build an app, which uses the firebase realtime database. The database has this neat feature, to listen for changes for a specific child node. As far as I know, this will only work, when the app is in the foreground and not closed, right?

The thing is, if the app is in the background, I want to trigger a notification for specific users. This won't work with the database, because the app is closed. Obviously I need to use cloud messaging in this case, to wake the device up and display a notification. I could listen to changes in my realtime database via node.js and then send a push notification to the user => this requires a server in-between, which I try to avoid.

Is there any way to achieve that,

- when the app is in the foreground => trigger changes via realtime
  database
- when the app is in the background => display notification via cloud
  messaging

without having a server on my own and just using the [firebase technology](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)? [Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) only serves static files and [storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) is (well) only for storing files like images.

Comment: actually, listeners remains active, when app in background. On Android. On iOS there is no way. Firebase team promised to make push messages on DB events, but I don't have strong believes about that

Comment: When app is in background = when the activity is still in the memory? But what if the memory is wiped? They won't work then, right?

Comment: create service, and set listeners in it. On SO there are several solutions, how to make service undestroyable

Comment: @Chris: what platform are you targeting? Because as Dima explains: the answer is rather different between iOS and Android.

Comment: Android first, but iOS is planned for the future.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So you think it's possible (for Android) just with the realtime database and a long running service?

Comment: On Android you **can** keep the listeners alive, by putting them in a service. But it's a bad idea for battery life. On iOS you don't have the option at all. Sending downstream notifications/messages will require a server at the moment. That has been covered quite a lot already.

Comment: I haven't noticed high battery drain with Android service with listeners, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed in comments, and @Frank agree with me, currently the only thing you can do without server - put database listeners inside service, but it probably will cause some battery drain. On iOS you don't have any option at all.

I sent feature request to Firebase 5 days ago, answer was

> Hi Dima,
>
> Thanks for reaching out.
>
> We're definitely aware that many users, such as yourself, would like
>   this feature. We're exploring potential solutions, but I can't share
>   any details or timelines at this time. We'll keep your feedback in
>   consideration moving forward though.
>
> Keep an eye out on our release notes for any further updates.
>
> Regards,
>
> Marcial
>
> 27 Aug 2016

Comment: You have a link to your feature request?

Comment: Nope, I requested it by email. No other way. But you can send the same request, maybe they will pay more attention to this. I requested "Push messages on DB events"